# Django in Google App Engine - Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am in the process of migrating some GAE apps from Python 2.5 to 2.7. It seems much more difficult to import Django templates (any version) into this version of Python. I followed Google's instructions to the T and scoured the web for help, but ultimately failed. So here is what I tried, and I was wondering if any of you guys would be able to help me! Thanks in advance.

In app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
```

In main.yaml:

```
import os
# specify the name of your settings module
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
app = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The main class:

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html', None))
```

The Error I get:

> NameError: global name 'template' is not defined

Interestingly, it worked with Jinja2 templates. However, all HTML code was written using Django templates and I think it would be too time consuming to convert them all. Here's the Jinja2 code that worked (all in one code block for simplicity).

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render())
```

Comment: You are missing a definition for the variable `template`. This has nothing to do with the template engine.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the past I could just use: `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`. But that doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: `webapp` is a different framework from Django. Did you follow the Django tutorials at all on how to define templates and use them?

Comment: In fact, you are not using Django in your main app, you are still using `webapp`. Adding Django to your yaml file will not magically make `webapp` know about Django templates.

Comment: ohh woops, I see now :)  So in the past I guess I was using webapp for my main app and Django templates for HTML. Do you know if it's possible to do the same in GAE python 2.7? I guess that's what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: basically, I'm trying to accomplish what I did with jinja2, but with django templates instead.

Comment: Ah, I see; the GAE documentation for 2.5 has the Django template engine integrated with the `webapp` library, the 2.7 documentation merely states that it is supported without an example. Have you tried running the 2.5-style code on 2.7?

Comment: yes, it gives me the error `Fatal error when loading application configuration:
the library "webapp" is not supported`

Comment: And changing `webapp` to `webapp2` doesn't work either? Note that `jinja2` is basically a stand-alone library for the same template language; from the [documentation page for jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/): *modelled after Django’s templates.*

Comment: nope, I get HTTP Error 500 (server error). The logs say `ImportError: cannot import name webapp2`

Comment: Basically, I edited `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template` to `from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template`. Im guessing the server probably couldn't locate the latter.

Comment: [`webapp2` features](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/features.html#compatible-with-webapp) states it's backwards compatible with `webapp`. The [GAE documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp) says you can just do `import webapp2`. Have you tried `from webapp2 import template`?

Comment: I just tried. HTTP Error 500 again. This is in the GAE logs:`from webapp2 import template
ImportError: cannot import name template`

Comment: adding `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template` makes it work. I don't know why it wasn't working when you had suggested it to me.

Comment: I think I know what happened: I had both `import webapp` and `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`. It was supposed to be `import webapp2` and `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
`. Thanks so much for your help! I wish I could somehow accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `template` is undefined; you'll need to import it from `webapp`:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

`webapp2` is backwards compatible with `webapp` but you'll need to use the template engine from `webapp` still, see [Using templates](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html).